# Как сделать движение персонажа по стенам тунеля, без пустышки посередине?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проблема в том, что это не удобно для других людей в проекте ( те кто уровень будут строить ), так как пустышка (пустышка - это обьект в котором ничего нет, но он держит персонажа) должна быть ровно по середине тунеля ( игрок - это дочерний обьект пустышки, когда кручу пустышку по x, то крутится сам игрок ) и я сам не знаю как определить, где середина тунеля. Не совсем удобно короче. И вторая причина почему мне это не нравится - это, то, что если тунель начнет поворачиватся, то пустышка продолжит лететь вперед, и в итоге персонаж улетит за тунель. Как можно сделать это нормально? Чтобы было и удобно и многофункционально. Предлагали добавить коллайдер к тунелю, но до конца не обьснили зачем, так как непонятно, как двигать его по кругу и вообще вперед.

Видео как сейчас:

https://youtu.be/euzJ9S1PvnE

Иерархия:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код находится на обьекте Player:

```
void FixedUpdate ()
  {
    transform.position += transform.right * Time.fixedDeltaTime * force;

    Vector3 acceleration = Input.acceleration;

      transform.Rotate(new Vector3(acceleration.x * sidewaysForce * Time.fixedDeltaTime,0,0));

  }
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: можно попробовать сделать саму трубу триггером и внутри трубы в этом триггере персонажу делать ускорение к себе под ноги сильнее чем земное притяжение. Я бы пытался все решить с физической точки зрения в первую очередь, и лишь если не удасться это сделать через физику - пытаться городить костыли с пустышками.

Comment: Я бы пускал из пустышки лучи в 4 стороны (верх, низ, лево, право) и контролировал чтобы их длина всегда была равна, это решит проблему с позиционированием и поворотами